# Deconstruct a joined string passed to function?

Tags: python

I have a function to write out a nicely formatted report for a script I am writing. To do this I send the strings to write to the file into multiple functions as such:

```
workingTitle, workingContent = "\n\n\t\t\t Successful Downloads: \n\n", ("(" + str(iterator) + "): " +str(key) +str(value) +"\n")
            self.dictWriting(self, self.workingLinks, workingTitle, workingContent, None, file)
```

Where iterator is the index to be written to the file and the key/value is for the data within the dictionary I use.

My issue with this is the following. When I send this string to the function:

```
"(" + str(iterator) + "): " +str(key) +str(value) +"\n"
```

The function I use is what loops through the dictionary and assigns the variables iterator, key and value their proper values. For now I have temporarily used None but this does not fix the issue.

Is it possible to send this joint string over in a way that doesn't require the variables to be filled and then fill the values within the function?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Yes, you can use a so-called `f-string`. Or `str.format()`.

Comment: Also, please provide a bit more code. See [mcve] for some tips for creating a good code example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use an `f-string` or `str.format()`.

Comment: I would say this answer is poor, but it's well on par with the quality of the question...

Comment: @niCkcAMel Yes, without more details, this is my best guess at what the OP needs.